# Удаление данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Добрый вечер, не могли бы вы помочь написать правильно запросы на удаление данных из БД? Задача состоит в том, что по определенному ID отделения нужно также удалить группы которые туда входят и студентов групп. Я понимаю что это нужно делать 3 разными запросами, но я не до конца понимаю как получить список ID из групп и как его использовать для удаления студентов. Примерно такая структура БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если в лоб, то `delete from students where group in(select id from groups where department_code in(...)` и так далее углубляясь

Comment: Эммм... а `ON DELETE CASCADE` не лучше ли будет?